# The scanf is not reading the values

Tags: c

Hey this is the entire code.
I m a beginner in C, I was trying to make a code which has a structure mall and takes into input the name, number of items shopped , the name of each item and the cost of each item.
* For small programs like this i fix the max size of the structure object
But the program cant take the input in the manner desired.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct mall

{

    char name[50];
    char obj[10][30];
    float price[10];
    int numb;
}b[50];

void main()

{

    int m; // number of persons who shopped at the mall

    scanf("%d",&m);

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        num=0;
        scanf("%s",&b[i].name);
        scanf("%d",&b[i].numb);
        printf("%s\n%d",b[i].name,b[i].numb);
        for(int j=0;j<num;j++)
        {
            scanf("%s",&b[i].obj);
            scanf("%f",&b[i].price);
        }
    }    
}
```

For the input :

```
1
Ram 2 bread 50.00 jam 25.00
```

I m getting the output as

2500

Comment: Not once do you check the return value from `scanf()`.  It returns a value for a reason.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&b[i].name);` -> `scanf("%s",b[i].name);`

Comment: `obj` and `price` are arrays. You evidently meant to use `j` as the index into those arrays.

Comment: Read carefully the documentation of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and of every other function you are using. Compile your code with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and **use the debugger**. *Fix-my-code* questions and *do-my-homework* questions are off-topic on SO.

Comment: I dont know why I was putting num=0. Actually there was a line num=b[i].numb. The variable num was being used somewhere else, this is just a snippet of the part of the code not used.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has many small mistakes:

- `scanf("%s", &b[i].name);` does not need `&`
- `num=0;` is not necessary; remove it
- Nested loop condition should use `j < b[i].numb` as its condition
- Nested loop is not using `j`. It needs to add `[j]` to both `obj` and `price`.

Once you fix these problems, your code runs as expected as long as the input is correct ([demo](https://ideone.com/fW6QrJ)).

However, this is not enough to make your code robust: you need to add error checking to ensure that invalid input does not cause undefined behavior:

- Add limits to string format specifiers in `scanf` to avoid buffer overflows (e.g. `%49s` to read `name[50]`),
- Add a limit to the outer loop in case `m` is above 50,
- Add a limit to the nested loop in case `b[i].numb` is above 10,
- Add checks of return values for `scanf`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I dont know why I was putting num=0.  Actually there was a line num=b[i].numb. The variable num was being used somewhere else, this is just a snippet of the part of the code not used. Thanks btw, it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

- `num` is undeclared.  The program does not compile to executable.  See below.
- Don't pass `&b[i].name` to `scanf(3)`, as the `%s` format requires a `char *` and the `&b[i].name` is not that type (it is, indeed, `char *[50]`, while compatible, it is not the same type, while `b[i].name` is)
- change `num` by `b[i].numb` in the inner `for` loop.  This is the proper number of items.  You have to check for array sizes also, as you have hardwired them in the code.  If you don't you can overrun
- Use inside the inner loop `b[i].obj[j]` for the object name as the reference to `scanf(3)`
- Use inside the inner loop `&b[i].price[j]` for the `j`-esim `price`.  You have forgotten it here and in the point above.
- you have to add code to print the individual objects (the inner loop has no `printf(3)` at all.

A valid (but not completely correct, as array sizes are not checked) could be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct mall {
    char name[50];
    char obj[10][30];
    float price[10];
    int numb;
}b[50];

int main()
{
    int m; // number of persons who shopped at the mall
    scanf("%d",&m);
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        scanf("%s",b[i].name);
        scanf("%d",&b[i].numb);
        printf("* name = %s\n"
                       "  numb = %d\n",b[i].name,b[i].numb);
        for(int j=0; j < b[i].numb; j++) {
            scanf("%s",b[i].obj[j]);
            scanf("%f",&b[i].price[j]);
                    printf("  * obj = %s\n", b[i].obj[j]);
                    printf("    price = %.2f\n", b[i].price[j]);
        }
    }    
    return 0;
}
```